# How to remove channel?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-server-2012

i'm trying to upgrade a windows 2012 core to windows 2012 gui, but it keeps failing.

This is the error from cbs.log:

```
2013-10-11 03:38:14, Error                 CSI    00000039 (F) Logged @2013/10/11:01:38:14.314 : [ml:304{152},l:302{151}]"events installer: online=1, install=1, component=amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Component-Resources-MrmCore_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_neutral_release__."
[gle=0x80004005]
2013-10-11 03:38:14, Error                 CSI    0000003a (F) Logged @2013/10/11:01:38:14.345 : [ml:294{147},l:292{146}]"EventAITrace:Channel Operational is declared by an existing provider Microsoft-Exchange-Troubleshooters{{d46a5e4c-6a53-411f-91f1-d205c8310818}}.

"
[gle=0x80004005]
2013-10-11 03:38:14, Error                 CSI    0000003b (F) Logged @2013/10/11:01:38:14.345 : [ml:168{84},l:166{83}]"WmiCmiPlugin manproc.cpp(709): InstrumentationManifestAssert failed. HR=0x80073aa2."
[gle=0x80004005]
2013-10-11 03:38:14, Error                 CSI    0000003c (F) Logged @2013/10/11:01:38:14.345 : [ml:166{83},l:164{82}]"WmiCmiPlugin eventloghandler.cpp(192): ProcessEventsInstall failed. HR=0x80073aa2."
[gle=0x80004005]
2013-10-11 03:38:14, Error                 CSI    0000003d (F) Logged @2013/10/11:01:38:14.345 : [ml:170{85},l:168{84}]"WmiCmiPlugin eventloghandler.cpp(212): EventLogHandlerInstall failed. HR=0x80073aa2."
[gle=0x80004005]
2013-10-11 03:38:14, Error                 CSI    0000003e@2013/10/11:01:38:14.345 (F) CMIADAPTER: Inner Error Message from AI HRESULT = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(15010)
 [
[22]"Configuration error.

"
```

I think the problem is here: EventAITrace:Channel Operational is declared by an existing provider Microsoft-Exchange-Troubleshooters{{d46a5e4c-6a53-411f-91f1-d205c8310818}}.

But how do i remove the channel?

Answer (score 0):

I found a hint to the answer [somewhere else](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itproinstall/thread/508f3800-5a40-4333-8409-9908a07f6fd9/#36fdffa9-f204-4ef9-822f-88f76290e03d). It mentions deleting all the keys, but I found out that it will cause more harm than good.

This is what fixed my Windows 2012 Core to Windows 2012 Full Gui upgrade:

1. In regedit go to HKLM/software/microsoft/windows/currentversion/winevt
2. Open the Channels folder and look for the mentioned channel. In my case: Operational.  Remove this key.
3. Then open the Publishers folder and look for the GUID that is mentioned in the error message (Microsoft-Exchange-Troubleshooters{{**d46a5e4c-6a53-411f-91f1-d205c8310818**}})
4. Remove this key as well

Now you can perform the upgrade, reboot and there will be no more "Failure configuring Windows updates. Reverting changes. Do not turn off your computer" errors.